# Can't change elements background color after being set by event listeners, vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, background-color

I dynamically created a grid of 10 by 10 div elements and put a mouse-over event listener on each of them to change the background color to black when the mouse passes over them.
The problem is that when I try to clear them (reset the background to white <I had to put "red" to actually see any changes>) it changes only the divs whose events listeners have not been triggered.

Ex: the divs are "white", mouse-over color is "black", and the clear color is "red" (because using white I can't see any changes). When I click the button to clear the grid (to red) only the div's that are not black (whose event listeners had not been triggered) change.

Why is that? Does the triggered event listener blocks me from changing the color, or is it something else?

Comment: You have to show your code. We don't know how your implemented it

Comment: I've solved it by adding a class to each div and then using that class to get a list of all the divs. Previously I used div. children